# SQL Server 2008 R2 and Code Igniter Connection

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, codeigniter

I am using windows 8 and am trying to use sqlserver 2008 as my database.
I installed sql driver (SQLSRV31.exe) and I have

```
php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
php_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
```

extracted to my php/ext. I have made changes to **php.ini** as

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

Similarly,this is my database configuration

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "127.0.0.1";
$db['default']['port'] = 1433;
$db['default']['username'] = 'sa';
$db['default']['password'] = '**';
$db['default']['database'] = 'db_test';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv'; 
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

But I keep on getting error as **Fatal error**:

```
Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\test\system\database\drivers\sqlsrv\sqlsrv_driver.php on line 76.
```

Could anyone please helpme with this?

Comment: I use several similar setups. In my database.php config files I use 
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'SERVER\SQLEXPRESS';  (where 'SERVER\SQLEXPRESS' is the 'server name' you can see in your sql server management Studio 'Connect to server' dialog) and it works fine. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853210/codeigniter-not-connecting-to-sql-server/36480986#36480986 for further details.