# Cannot connect Codeigniter to Sql Server 2016

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter-3

I want to connect sql server 2016 from codeigniter. My PHP Version is 5.6 on xampp. I have installed sql server on my local system windows 10,

I have followed these steps to connect to sql server.

https://futbolsalas15.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/7-steps-to-make-sql-server-and-codeigniter-works/

Now the error is **Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.** . I can login, create database, and create table using SQL sever management studio with the same parameter. But not with codeigniter. Any one can help ?

Comment: This post may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853210/codeigniter-not-connecting-to-sql-server?rq=1

Comment: I have also try with this.